# Maya Python invalid syntax # Line 1

Tags: python

I work with Python in Autodesk Maya. I have this script and i get this error

## Error: line 1: invalid syntax #

The script

```
from maya import cmds , OpenMaya
sel = cmds.ls(sl = 1 )
crv = "curveShape1"
for s in sel :
    pos = cmds.xform(s ,q = 1 , ws = 1 , t = 1)
    u = getUParam(pos , crv)
    name = s.replace("_LOC" , "_PCI")
    pci = cmds.createNode(""pointOnCurveInfo" , n = name )
    cmds.connectAttr(crv + '.worldSpace' , pci + '.inputCurve')
    cmds.setAttr(pci + '.parameter' , u )
    cmds.connectAttr( pci + '.position' , s + '.t')
```

Answer (score 0):

String literals in Python are formed using only " or ' for one line strings. For multiline strings you can use: """....

So, to solve the syntax error just change:

```
pci = cmds.createNode(""pointOnCurveInfo" , n = name )
```

To:

```
pci = cmds.createNode("pointOnCurveInfo" , n = name )
```

The second error is raised because the function getUParam is not defined at that moment, so you must define this getUParam function before using it, like this:

```
from maya import cmds , OpenMaya

def getUParam( pnt = [], crv = None):

    point = OpenMaya.MPoint(pnt[0],pnt[1],pnt[2])
    curveFn = OpenMaya.MFnNurbsCurve(getDagPath(crv))
    paramUtill=OpenMaya.MScriptUtil()
    paramPtr=paramUtill.asDoublePtr()
    isOnCurve = curveFn.isPointOnCurve(point)
    if isOnCurve == True:

        curveFn.getParamAtPoint(point , paramPtr,0.001,OpenMaya.MSpace.kObject )
    else :
        point = curveFn.closestPoint(point,paramPtr,0.001,OpenMaya.MSpace.kObject)
        curveFn.getParamAtPoint(point , paramPtr,0.001,OpenMaya.MSpace.kObject )

    param = paramUtill.getDouble(paramPtr)  
    return param

def getDagPath( objectName):

    if isinstance(objectName, list)==True:
        oNodeList=[]
        for o in objectName:
            selectionList = OpenMaya.MSelectionList()
            selectionList.add(o)
            oNode = OpenMaya.MDagPath()
            selectionList.getDagPath(0, oNode)
            oNodeList.append(oNode)
        return oNodeList
    else:
        selectionList = OpenMaya.MSelectionList()
        selectionList.add(objectName)
        oNode = OpenMaya.MDagPath()
        selectionList.getDagPath(0, oNode)
        return oNode

sel = cmds.ls(sl =1 )
crv = "curveShape1"
for s in sel :
    pos = cmds.xform(s ,q = 1 , ws = 1 , t = 1)
    u = getUParam(pos , crv)
    name = s.replace("_LOC" , "_PCI")
    pci = cmds.createNode("pointOnCurveInfo" , n = name )
    cmds.connectAttr(crv + '.worldSpace' , pci + '.inputCurve')
    cmds.setAttr(pci + '.parameter' , u )
    cmds.connectAttr( pci + '.position' , s + '.t')
```

Hope it helps,

Comment: Yes Tahnk you so much avenet but i have a new error. 
# Error: line 1: NameError: file <maya console> line 7: name 'getUParam' is not defined #

this is the whole script

# Error: line 1: NameError: file <maya console> line 7: name 'getUParam' is not defined #

Comment: tahnk you avenet but i have a new error with this new version of script
""" # Error: line 1: RuntimeError: file S:\Maya_2016_DI\build\Release\runTime\Python\Lib\site-packages\maya\OpenMaya.py line 10923: (kInvalidParameter): Object does not exist #  ""

Comment: Sorry @RaoufBessghaier, I can't help you anymore as this is a question related to Maya, check the values of the pnt list are OK and if you cannot see anything suspicious, post another question this time about Maya. If my answer was helpful to you, I'd appreciate if you can vote it up and mark it as correct. Thank you.